# Pentadactyl: Open a link in the current tab even when the link opens in a new tab by default

Tags: firefox, pentadactyl

Contrary what the documentation states, ;o does not open the selected link in the current tab but either opens it in the current tab or a new tab depending on the behaviour specified by the page. How can I force a link to always open in the current tab?

Comment: The TabMixPlus extension extension gives very good control over where links are opened. I've not tried the combination you want, but the context menu always allows opening in the current tab.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a two-step process: Copy address to clipboard, then open clipboard URL in current tab.

  <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><hint keys><kbd>p</kbd>
- Or, without using the clipboard, directly open an `:open <URL>` ex prompt with the link's URL, then just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

  <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><hint keys><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- You can create a new command for this is you like. Add the following code to your .pentadactylrc file:

  ```
  js hints.addMode('0','Force open in current tab',function(elem) dactyl.open(elem.href));
  ```

  Then you can simply use <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> followed by the hint keys.